# How to remove a key from a minor-mode keymap in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I have globally assigned `C-c/` to ace-jump-mode but reftex-mode (a minor mode for citations used with AucTeX) overrides this key with some function I never use.

I tried `local-unset-key` but it only unbinds keys from the current *major* mode's map.

How do I remove `C-c/` from `reftex-mode-map` without making changes to reftex.el?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can change an existing key map using `define-key`. By passing `nil` as the function to call, the key will become unbound. I guess that you should be able to do something like:

```
(define-key reftex-mode-map "\C-c/" nil)
```

Of course, you should do this in some kind of hook, for example:

```
(defun my-reftex-hook ()
  (define-key reftex-mode-map "\C-c/" nil))
(add-hook 'reftex-mode-hook 'my-reftex-hook)
```

Comment: No.  Don't call define-key from hooks except for very specific modes that aggressively enforce its own binding.  I actually can't think of any examples.  Each minor/major mode only has one keymap, so there is no point in repeatedly modifying it every time you enter the mode.  Use `eval-after-load` instead.

Comment: Thanks to both.  It didn't occur to me to use nil to undefine a key.  The eval-after-load tip completes the answer. I'll accept the answer and +1 the comment.

Comment: To be clear, @event_jr is suggesting something like `(eval-after-load 'reftex '(define-key reftex-mode-map "\C-c/" nil))`. The first argument to `eval-after-load` -- here `reftex` -- is the name that the mode "provides".

Comment: in response to event_jr, here's an example of aggressively enforcing a mode's own binding: flyspell-mode. Occasionally it overwrites my key bindings even though I used eval-after-load to set it to null and then set it in my mode to what I want.

Comment: `(define-key reftex-mode-map "\C-c/" nil :append t)` Append in case the binding itself is defined in a hook.

Answer (score 7):

You can use following command:

```
(define-key reftex-mode-map "\C-c/" nil)
```

to unmap this function from `C-c /`... But `reftex-mode` should be loaded, so `reftex-mode-map` will available for modification

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. It could be improved, though.

```
 (defun get-key-combo (key)
  "Just return the key combo entered by the user"
  (interactive "kKey combo: ")
  key)

(defun keymap-unset-key (key keymap)
    "Remove binding of KEY in a keymap
    KEY is a string or vector representing a sequence of keystrokes."
    (interactive
     (list (call-interactively #'get-key-combo)
           (completing-read "Which map: " minor-mode-map-alist nil t)))
    (let ((map (rest (assoc (intern keymap) minor-mode-map-alist))))
      (when map
        (define-key map key nil)
        (message  "%s unbound for %s" key keymap))))
;;
;; Then use it interativly
;; Or like this:

(keymap-unset-key  '[C-M-left]   "paredit-mode")
..
..
```

Comment: This is mostly useful for interactively use. I usually do that to find out which map to remove the key from, and the name of the key.  It is easier then looking up in the source-code to find the map, and to know the **name of the key** to unbind. For example Ctrl-|  is the key [67108988].  Then I use repeat-complex-command and cut and paste it in to .emacs.